# Can't see SQLAlchemy Engine with default pool settings establishing more then one connection at a time

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I need some help with understanding connection pooling from SQLAlchemy perspective and Redshift perspective.

Ultimately what I want to achieve:

- Maximize query parallelism but save Redshift from connections exhaustion
- Avoid bottleneck of connection pool while Redshift performing really well but Python application has not enough connections and queries are starting to form a large queue

I have a few instances of application running in docker containers, each instance creates its own SQLAlchemy Engine object with default pooling settings.

```
engine = create_engine(REDSHIFT_URI, echo=True, echo_pool=True)
```

I also use context management model suggested in SQLAlchemy documentation and execute each query inside this context. All my queries are aggregation select queries.

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    session = Session(engine)
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

I count all Redshift sessions with `select count(*) from stv_sessions where user_name != ‘rdsdb’`. The number of sessions is the same as the number of application containers.

Then I start to trigger tons of queries from application  I don’t see the increase in Redshift sessions count. Also I can’t see any messages from SQLAlchemy pool logging.

From Redshift documentation:

> Each session corresponds to a connection. You can view information
>   about the active user sessions for Amazon Redshift, or you can check
>   the total number of the connections by using STV_SESSIONS.

From my understanding SQLAlchemy should open 5 connections but I can’t see it neither in Redshift nor in application logs. Does SQLAlchemy just reuse one connection all the time? Is the definition of SQLAlchemy connection is different from definition in Redshift?

Where is the flow in my logic? Looks like either my testing is bad or I didn’t get one of the concepts.

Comment: Do your instances of application run queries concurrently? If not, then there's no need for the pool to create new connections. That 5 is the soft limit, but does not mean that the pool will pre-emptively create that many connections.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks, I see. I realized that I was hitting the same synchronous endpoint while testing, which means that queries had no chance to run concurrently because endpoint only handles one request with a query at a time. Will try to hit a few endpoints simultaneously

Comment: Note that Redshift has a maximum limit of 500 connections, but a maximum _concurrency_ for queries of 50 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html However, the maximum *recommended* concurrency is just 15 over all WLM queues. Parallelising queries across connections does not necessarily mean they will actually run in parallel unless there are free WLM queue slots for them to run in.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths thank for this comment, good point, looks like I should stick to default pooling settings for now anyway

Answer (score -2):

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html

Create a `Pool`

```
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
import psycopg2

def getconn():
    c = psycopg2.connect(username='ed', host='127.0.0.1', dbname='test')
    return c

mypool = pool.QueuePool(getconn, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5)
e = create_engine('postgresql://', pool=mypool)
```